# .net-Framework - trouble creating Multi-target framework (MTF) library .netstandard21 / .net60 on Jenkins CI

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins, multitargeting

task: upgrade services from .netcore31 to .net6

the idea: creating MTF-libraries referencing net6 and (netcore31 or netstandard21)

how: jenkins, docker on linux

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
copy --FROM=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /usr/share/dotnet/shared /usr/share/dotnet/shared
```

building and using the created MTF library - all is well

the trouble: using the library created by Jenkins job fails

```
Error   CS1705  Assembly '...***...* uses 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

any ideas? What is missing on docker or jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I found that both netcore3.1 and net6.0 libraries were targeting net6.0 (Can see this in dotPeek). Instead of one targeting 6 and one targeting 3.1. Problem was the build command had an output folder so both frameworks were outputted to the same location, meaning one overwrote the other.

```
dotnet build "****" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Should be

```
dotnet build "****" -c Release
```